# laravel password validation in separate class

Tags: laravel, validation, passwords

I created a rule \App\Rules\password.php

in the UserValidation I call it

```
$rules['password'] = ['required', new Password(), 'confirmed'];
```

if I dd() to the screen I see

```
"email" => array:2 [▶]
  "firstName" => "required"
  "lastName" => "required"
  "phoneNumbers" => array:1 [▶]
  "phoneNumbers.phone" => array:2 [▶]
  "password" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "required"
    1 => App\Rules\Password {#721}
    2 => "confirmed"
  ]
```

I am Stuck trying to use this code
If I take out the dd() It will simply pass without validate

What am I missing ?? I need help on this

Comment: Your question doesn't show us the code for the rule, or what input you're passing it, or give any reason why it *shouldn't* pass validation.

Comment: Also, the file should be Password not password.  Post the rule so we can check namespace and classname